# Close application from broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm new in android programming.
I've tried registering broadcast receiver in activity, but my receiver not working when apps onPause.
So i found that i need to registering my receiver in manifest.

My objective is to close my application for some time after user turn off Wifi.

This is my code but its not working.

```
public class ReceiverWifi extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainActivity m = new MainActivity();
                m.finish();

            }
        };

        if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {

            int newWifiState = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE,
                    WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN);

            switch (newWifiState) {

            case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED:

                Toast.makeText(context, "Wi-fi Disconnected ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 15 * 1000);
                break;

            }
        }

    }
}
```

my manifest :

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.wifimonitor.ReceiverWifi" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

How do i achieve my objective?

Comment: have u written any code on onPause()  .if so please post it

Comment: no code on onPause()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your broadcast receiver is in the main activity class? If so you can save a global context of your app and close it later in the broadcast receiver.

If it is on a service or provider, just send an instance of your app to it when you start/register it. Then you call finish() from that instance.

**EDIT:**

Try this:

In your main activity create this public method:

```
   public static void closeActivity(){
        finish();
   }
```

Then in your broadcast receiver call this method like:

```
   MainActivity.closeActivity();
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: i have my ReceiverWifi as a new class, how do i send an instance to it?

Comment: i got this error : Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method finish() from the type Activity

Comment: Change `finish()` for `MainActivity.finish()`... or create a `private static Context context;` in your `onCreat` you do `context = this;` and then in the `closeActivity()` method you do `context.finish();`

Comment: @margabro it's not working for me.. :( giving the same error.i tried your solution 'in comments' ,then it says cannot resolve method `finish(); ` If I define finish it gives can't refer non-static from static,if i declare finish as static it gives static method finish cannot override instance method.. :( :(

Comment: It is obviously not working, finish is a non-static method as it performs an action over an instace, if there is no instace you cant call the finish(). Anyone has a better solution?

Answer (score 3):

Use code below to send new intent to MainActivity from BroadcastReceiver:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.addFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
i.putExtra("close_activity",true);
context.startActivity(i);
```

in MainActivity use OnNewIntent as below:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if(intent.getBooleanExtra("close_activity",false)){
        this.finish();

    }
}
```

FYI, I haven't tried the above code, But I have similar code working.

Answer (score -1):

```
MainActivity m = new MainActivity();
m.finish();
```

When you say finish, it wont clear from stack because you didn't loaded the activity into stack first.
The MainActivity is not activity here, it is just a class object in your code

Have broadcast receiver in mainactivity, when onreceive finish the activity. don't create instance with new.

Comment: i need my broadcast receiver in another class, how to do it?