# Stop Process when Notification is Cleared

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want the application process to be killed when the user slides the notification off the screen or hits the clear all notifications button.

Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671453/catch-on-swipe-to-dismiss-event

Answer (score 0):

**DeleteIntent**: DeleteIntent is a PendingIntent object that can be associated with a notification and gets fired when the notification gets deleted.

You can set the Pending Intent to a broadcast Receiver and then perform any action you want.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
  Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this):
 ..... code for your notification
  builder.setDeleteIntent(pendingIntent);
```

**MyBroadcastReceiver**

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         //code to kill app
         c̶o̶n̶t̶e̶x̶t̶.̶f̶i̶n̶i̶s̶h̶A̶f̶f̶i̶n̶i̶t̶y̶(̶)̶;̶
         ActivityCompat.finishAffinity((Activity)context);
     }
}
```

reference: [catch on swipe notification event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671453/catch-on-swipe-to-dismiss-event)

Comment: Where is `finishAffinity()` defined, the receiver does not resolve the method. I've tried the alternatives given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134560/close-application-from-broadcast-receiver) as well but none of them are working